# How to reuse header section all scene?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to reuse `header` section all `view controller scene` .header section mean green view and label ("AMAR LIFE")

**Here is my may 1st view controller scene**
[image]

**Here is my 1st view controller document outline**

[image]

Comment: you can create your own UIView in a separated xib file, load it from bundle and add it to the main view(s).

Comment: @AhmadF is it best option to make application header ? if not then please suggest me

Comment: I'm not pretty sure of what you are aiming to do, I prefer to let UINavigation bar do its native behaviour. However, if you need to get the view from the bundle and add it as a subview, you should take care of how you will setup constraints for it.

Comment: @Joe what should i do ?

Comment: code updated........

Comment: A *scene* in a storyboard is the view hierarchy associated with a single view controller instance. Your first illustration shows five scenes, not one.

Comment: @Caleb thanks to detected the good point .  i am new to swift please suggest  me which content or book i should be flowing . thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand the question. Do you want to reuse the actual view that displays your banner? (And if so, why?) Or just reuse the code that draws it? Do you want a programmatic solution or a storyboard solution? What's unsatisfactory about the solutions already proposed? (Also, your storyboard image would be easier to understand if you didn't line up the scenes so that all the segues overlap.)

Comment: Do you gonna accept my answer?

Comment: @Joe accepted your answer and voted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following steps to achieve your header visible on all views.

**Step 1:** Drag a navigationController into your storyBoard and delete tableView rootViewcontroller comes with the naviagtionController.Connect your NavigationController to your tabBarController.Now,NavigationController available to all your view.

**Note:** Your storyBoard layout should be look like a below image..

[image]

**Step 2:** Implement following code to your FirstTabBarController.

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Apply transparency to NavigationBar.
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

    //Setting up scanView background
    let barView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:view.frame.width,height: (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height)) 
    barView.backgroundColor=UIColor.green // set any colour you want..
    barView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    barView.layer.borderWidth = 3
    navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(barView)

   //Setting up labelView
    let label = UILabel()
    label.frame = CGRect(x:25, y:5, width:view.frame.width - 50 , height:((navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height) - 10)
    label.text = "AMAR LIFE"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = .black
    label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-medium", size: CGFloat(40))
    label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    label.layer.borderWidth = 3
    barView.addSubview(label)

}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Subclass UITabBarController. Make the green view a subview *of the tab bar controller's main view*. Whenever the selected view controller changes (or anything else happens), keep bringing the green view to the front. (Even better, make the green view a layer, not a view, and give it a higher z-position so that it automatically floats in front of all subviews.)

Comment: Basically your goal here is to make your tab bar controller do with this green view exactly the same thing it does with its tab bar! The tab bar is in front of all view controller views; you want the green view to do that too.

Comment: Even easier way! Put the tab bar controller inside a navigation controller and make the navigation bar green. The navigation controller never actually navigates anywhere: its job is merely to host the nav bar. It already knows how to put the nav bar in front of everything else, so you have no further work to do. However, it will be at the top of the screen, not like in your drawing.

Comment: Putting a tab bar controller inside a navigation controller has never been supported. Unless things have changed recently, [a tab bar controller can contain a navigation controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH6-SW1), but not the other way around.

Comment: @coderLIfe I don't know what you want from me. I've given my suggestion. If you don't like it, don't accept it. My suggestion was based on your initial screen shot which showed a tab bar controller and a bunch of its children. Now you post another screen shot showing a completely different configuration? I don't play that kind of bait-and-switch game, sorry. What I have said, I have said.

Answer (score -2):

you need to add the following method in every view controller

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "123"), for: .default)
    self.title = "Hi I am tittle"
}
```

Also if you want to avoid code duplication and do more good just create one parent UIview and write this method in it and then inherit it in all the other views. However both solutions work fine.
you can change the title and image according to your needs. 
Thanks

Comment: i have no navigation controller

Comment: then simply use self and remove the navigationController.