# Swift: UITabBar with a sharing header on all screens

Tags: swift

I am trying to build a App right now based on a UITabBar. My TabBar should just change a area on my screen, not the complete screen. Thats why I am not using the UITabBarController.

So if I am adding now a UITabBar on to my UIViewController I dont know how I can tell my tabs which View they have to change to which ViewController.

Here is also a picture of what I mean. On the picture I want to have always the brown background and on top my label. The UIView iss the section where I want to change the View Controllers View 1 and 2 with the tab bar items. Is that possible?
[image]

Comment: Yes, it's possible using [the view controllers containment API](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html).

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40338691/how-to-reuse-header-section-all-scene/40352965#40352965

Comment: @Sonius I added an example below.

Comment: Host UITabBarViewController inside UINavigationViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made an example of what I think you're trying to achieve. Tapping a tab bar button shows its respective view controller inside the yellow view.

[image: storyboard layout]

First arrange three view controllers in Interface Builder as shown above. Drag a plain `UIView` (not a Container View) onto the main view controller and position it (using constraints as needed). Add the tab bar below (set its delegate) and label as shown.

Then Control-drag to create a segue from your main view controller to each of the child view controllers. When the popup appears to select the segue type, **choose Custom**:

[image: choose segue type as custom]

Then click each segue connection and in the Attributes Inspector, give each an identifier (e.g. `first` and `second`), and set their class to `MySegue` (a custom segue we'll create shortly):

[image: set the custom segue's class and identifier]

Assuming the main view controller is set to the class `ViewController`, replace ViewController.swift with the following:

```
class MySegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        // Leave empty (we override prepareForSegue)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Load the first screen by default.
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "first", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue is MySegue {

            // This is an example of how to use the UIViewController containment APIs.
            // If we're starting, there is not yet a child view controller added, so
            // just add it.
            if childViewControllers.count == 0 {

                self.addChildViewController(segue.destination)
                segue.destination.view.frame = containerView.bounds
                self.containerView.addSubview(segue.destination.view)
                segue.destination.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

            // If there is already a child, swap it with the segue's destination view controller.
            } else {

                let oldViewController = self.childViewControllers[0]
                segue.destination.view.frame = oldViewController.view.frame
                oldViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
                self.addChildViewController(segue.destination)
                self.transition(from: oldViewController, to: segue.destination, duration: 0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: nil) { completed in
                    oldViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
                    segue.destination.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        guard let index = tabBar.items?.index(of: item) else { return }
        switch index {
        case 0:
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "first", sender: nil)
        case 1:
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "second", sender: nil)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Now wire up the IBOutlet of `containerView` to the yellow view of the main view controller.

Compile and observe how tapping the tab bar buttons switches between the two view controllers inside the yellow view, maintaining the shared label above.

This is an example of the UIViewController containment APIs.

Comment: That sounds like what I am wanting to get. But if I am implementing your code then the ViewController tries to call performSegue I get just the following error: 'Could not create a segue of class '(null)''. And I never get into prepare(for because of that.

Comment: found the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687726/xcode-custom-segue-class-stuck thank you!

Comment: Awesome, is it anything I can add to the answer to make it clearer?

Comment: Yeah. at this point I needed to do one step more: Then click each segue connection and in the Attributes Inspector, give each an identifier (e.g. first and second), set their class to MySegue (a custom segue we'll create shortly) AND set Module to your project name:

Comment: @paulvs You solution is amazing you just forgot to wire up an IBOutlet for the UITabBar to the viewController and on `viewDidLoad()`set it's delegate to self. 
Also the animation should be drawn as per index position so the swipe is weather from left to right or just the opposite.